# How do you uninstall a Map Pack on Call of Duty Ghosts (PS4)?

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-ghosts

Is it possible to uninstall the Onslaught Map Pack for Call of Duty: Ghosts on Playstation 4?

There was a recent update that merged the Map Pack lobbies with the normal, default map lobbies and now everyone always votes for the new maps.

Unfortunately, neither myself or my brother are fans of the new maps so was hoping to uninstall them so only the original maps appear in a lobby.

I've tried going to the "downloads" section and deleting the file, but they still appear in the team death match lobby...

Any guidance or sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to remove the DLC maps from the rotation. From [here](https://community.callofduty.com/t5/Call-of-Duty-Ghosts-Support/Can-you-turn-off-DLC-in-rotation-or-delete-just-map-files/td-p/9322911):

> You can delete  the individual map packs that you purchased at any time you like. The purchase will remain in your " history" so you can reinstall at any time you so desire. Just go to library on your top menu bar, find  ghosts, click on it , find your map packs( should be listed separately ) then uninstall the pack you want. This should take it out of the rotation, good luck- let us know if that helps!